# Phabricator installation problem " FATAL ERROR: Unable to load the "Arcanist" library. Put "arcanist/" next to "phabricator/" on disk."

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phabricator, arcanist

I'm trying to install Phabricator with that documentation: https://websiteforstudents.com/install-phabricator-platform-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-with-apache2-mariadb-and-php-7-2

When i use "`sudo ./bin/config set mysql.host localhost`" command there was a error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Unable to load the "Arcanist" library. Put "arcanist/" next to "phabricator/" on disk.
```

Any solution?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Troubleshooting shows that the file `./phabricator/scripts/init/lib.php` is attempting the line `$ok = @include_once 'arcanist/scripts/init/init-script.php';`. The directory `./arcanist/scripts/` does not contain an `init` directory. I installed Phabricator using their `install_ubuntu.sh`. Perhaps it skipped something? Maybe a bug report needs to be done?

Comment: FYI, my file structure is `arcanist`, `phabricator`, and `libphutil` are all in `/usr/local/`  Looking at `https://github.com/phacility/arcanist/tree/master/scripts` there also is no `init` directory. Should some sort of setup have been called to craete it? There is an `__init_script__.php`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the most recent git commit is missing some critical files from the `arcanist` directory.

I downloaded commit `26f853b` from 2 days ago (26f853b6343083c3ddfb6a393843edb20248ee71.zip) from [here](https://github.com/phacility/arcanist/archive/26f853b6343083c3ddfb6a393843edb20248ee71.zip) and the script ran through. I haven't tested if phabricator actually works with it however.

You might want to submit a bugreport.

Answer (score 0):

I've received the same fatal when tried to upgrade the Phabricator via update script.

I did manual update in the path in

```
./phabricator/scripts/init/lib.php
```

from

```
"arcanist/scripts/init/init-script.php"
```

to

```
"arcanist/support/init/init-script.php"
```

after which the update script passed and storage upgrade was ok.

Maybe there was a typo and the "scripts" in the path should be "**support**".

Also reported here https://discourse.phabricator-community.org/t/the-phutil-library-phutil-has-not-been-loaded/3543/2